# Is it always better to use a releases branch in git?

Tags: git

I am using git along the lines of [this model](http://nvie.com/img/2009/12/Screen-shot-2009-12-24-at-11.32.03.png). I am about ready to do my first release. I don't work as part of a team, there's just me. Is there any necessity to use a 'releases' branch? I have a feeling it might be just complicating things and so I was going to just merge changes from the development branch directly into the master instead, and proceed with future releases in that way.

Comment: I would take a look at tags, instead.

Comment: I like creating a release branch, incase an issue comes up, but I don't want to push everything currently on master. It's better to have everything set up before you need it.

Comment: @vcsjones "instead" is the wrong word: You can have both // #topic: Branches are cheap in `git`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to create a release branch unless you want to start doing work on your develop branch that doesn't belong in the upcoming release.

Answer (score 0):

It is't *needed*, but if you want to ship version 1.0, while working towards 2.0 you'll want not to abandon the 1.x series, and cherry pick changes or apply local bugfixes. Having a release branch and development branch(es) is useful in that case.